# Converting Python List to Bytes Failing

Tags: python, arrays, string, encoding, byte

```
    def get_new_bytes(self):
        x = random.randint(1, 10)
        iv = list()
        for y in range(1, 17):
             iv.append(x)

        ret = bytes(iv)
        print(type(ret))
        return ret
```

My issue is that the type still shows as a string! I need a byte array! I've tried multiple things including .encode and still not working. I'm using python 2.7.

Thank you!

Comment: This works in Python 3.x btw

Comment: `str` in python 2.7 is a bytestring, so you're already there.

Comment: @MatthewStory Okay, that does seem to be true. Why does len(ret) come out to so much more than 16, it comes back at 80. I guess I should elaborate that I'm trying to make a bytes field of 16 bytes.

Comment: Okay, so thanks to @MatthewStory 's input I found a way to get this done.      def get_new_bytes(self):
        x = random.randint(1, 10)
        iv = str()
        for y in range(1, 17):
             iv += chr(x)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bytearray(ret)` to get a `<type 'bytearray'>`.